# Getting status code 500 when using Requests library to login for a scraping program. I'm out of ideas as to why this is occuring

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm building a scraper that grabs my electric usage data from Teco. When studying the dev tools network tab in Chrome, I placed each attribute of the form data and request headers in `POST` and I'm still getting 500. Here's my code:

```
res = requests.get("https://account.tecoenergy.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

login_form = soup.find("form", {"id": "LoginForm"})
# Getting the tokens for form data
verToken = login_form.find("input", {"name": "__RequestVerificationToken"})['value']
as_fid = login_form.find("input", {"name": "as_fid"})['value']


LOGIN_HEADERS = {"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
                    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
                    "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
                    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    "Connection": "keep-alive",
                    "Content-Length": "251",
                    "Host": "account.tecoenergy.com",
                    "Origin": "https://account.tecoenergy.com",
                    "Referer": "https://account.tecoenergy.com/Home",
                    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
                    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
                    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
                    "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
                    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1"}
USER_AGENT = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36"}

headers = LOGIN_HEADERS.copy()
headers.update(USER_AGENT)
data = {"__RequestVerificationToken":verToken, "Credentials.UserName": self._username, "Credentials.Password": self._password, "as_fid": as_fid}
with requests.Session() as s:
    response = s.post('https://account.tecoenergy.com/Account/Login', data=data, headers=headers, verify=True)

    print(response.status_code)
```

With the exception of the order of the header attributes and leaving out cookies (I'm assuming adding the Cookies part of the header is a function of `requests.Session()`), it's identical to what I'm seeing on the website.

I've looked everywhere, and I'm completely out of ideas as to why I can't login with the script. Has anyone seen this problem before? Or have an idea of what direction I should head in order to solve it?

Comment: You're doing the `get` outside of the session for one thing. So cookies won't be set on the next request.

Comment: @pguardiario Won't the cookies be set if I leave the rest of the `get` requests inside the `with` statement? Unless you're referring to the first `get` request which was needed to grab the `__RequestVerificationToken` and `as_fid` values from the login page.

Comment: You have to make all session requests with requests.Session() - I think that's the clearest way to put it.

Comment: @pguardiario You were right. That made all the difference. Thank you! It's always something so small that holds everything up for a week.